# Gree Enclave Reputation Vendor available?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

The Patch Notes from patch 2.7 says.

> New Legacy Offhands are now available from the Gree Enclave Galactic
>   Reputation Vendor.

The Gree Event isn't available right now. But can I still buy the weapons from the vendor, or do I have to wait until the Gree Event comes back live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vendor is always active, whether or not the event is.  Get thee to Ilum!

This is true for the Bounty Brokers event as well, but note that it is not the case for the Rakghoul event — the THORN gear vendor and the basic items vendor are available from the GSI area on Nar Shaddaa (Upper Promenade), but the rare items vendor Jeelvic the Jawa is only available in the Rakghoul Tunnels whilst the event is active.  The Life Day event vendor (the Master of Ceremonies) is only around while the event is active as well.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, nice edit!